# How can you install 3.11.x from 3.10?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I'm trying to upgrade my version of RabbitMQ using chocolatey. This package has Erlang as a dependency, so installs the relevant version required. I've gone from 3.9.19 to 3.10 fine. However, when I try and go from 3.10 to 3.11.7 I get the following error:

```
beam\beam_load.c(169): Error loading module elixir:
This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 24.
To fix this, please recompile this module with an 24 compiler.
(Use of opcode 178; this emulator supports only up to 176.)

ERROR! Failed to start Elixir.
error: {error,
           {elixir,
               {bad_return,
                   {{elixir,start,[normal,[]]},
                    {'EXIT',
                        {undef,
                            [{elixir,start,[normal,[]],[]},
                             {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                 [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                  {line,293}]}]}}}}}}
```

I don't know why this is happening, or if it's even a problem. I've not been able to find anything on this error. When I run RabbitMQ it *appears* to be running ok with the right version of Erlang. However, this error suggests that it's attempting to use Erlang version 24 (which was already installed as part of installing 3.9.19). How is it deciding what version of Erlang to use here? I checked my environment variables and it the ERLANG_HOME is set correctly.

**Update**

I tried going through the process again and installing rabbitmq 3.9.19 from chocolatey, upgrading to 3.10.1, then using the choco command to uninstall just Erlang 24.0 (using force). I then upgraded rabbitmq to version 3.11.8. This got rid of the previous error but showed another one stating:

> ERLANG_HOME not set correctly.
>
> Please either set ERLANG_HOME to point to your Erlang installation or
> place the RabbitMQ server distribution in the Erlang lib folder.

However, when I checked the ERLANG_HOME environment variable it seemed to be set correctly, in that it was pointing now at Erlang OTP and not erl-24.0. So why is this error thrown?

Comment: You need to _ONLY_ have Erlang 25 installed. I'm assuming you're on Windows.

Comment: @LukeBakken - yes, on windows. I tried using the manual 'uninstall.exe' in the erl-24.0 folder as well, to see if this would fix the issue, but even after uninstalling 24 it still throws this error.

Comment: Actually no, that's not quite true. I haven't tested uninstalling Erlang 24 on it's own before upgrading to 3.11.7. I'll try that.

Comment: I ended up resorting to doing a choco uninstall of the current version of rabbitmq and then doing a choco install of 3.11.7.

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest way to fix this situation. Thanks for following up.